# Create a Variable which refers to the Parameter of another Object?

Tags: c#

I have a pretty specific problem.
I have a custom class with various properties of the same type and I have a method elsewhere which needs to run on the class and compare those properties. The method needs to be able to compare these properties, but is instructed to compare different ones depending on the situation.

As it stands, I have a switch which takes a string to determine which properties to compare:

```
switch(field)
{
    case "int1":
        if (myClass1.int1 < myClass2.int1)
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
    case "int2":
        if (myClass1.int2 < myClass2.int2)
        {
            //do something
        }
        break;
}
```

Is there a way that I could just set a variable to refer to the property of the class which I want to refer which would allow just using the switch and have the code comparing the properties later? Something like this:

```
var referrer;
switch(field)
{
    case "int1":
        referrer = int1;
        break;
    case "int2":
        referrer = int2;
        break;
}

if (myClass1.referrer < myClass2.referrer)
{ //do something }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a `Func<T, int>` approach, something like:

```
public class SomeClass 
{ 
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
}

var one = new SomeClass { First = 1, Second = 5 };
var two = new SomeClass { First = 5, Second = 1 };

Func<SomeClass, int> referrer = null;

switch (field) 
{
    case "first":
        referrer = x => x.First;
        break;
    case "second":
        referrer = x => x.Second;
        break;
}

if (referrer(one) < referrer(two))
{

}
```

Of course, this assumes that you always want to compare `int` properties. Take a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g3XgUO).

There is another way, if you want to avoid the `switch` completely, and is to use Reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var one = new SomeClass { First = 1, Second = 5 };
        var two = new SomeClass { First = 5, Second = 1 };
        string field = "First";

        if (GetValue(one, field) < GetValue(two, field))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("one is smaller than two");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("one is greater than two");
        }
    }

    private static int GetValue(SomeClass someClass, string field) => Convert.ToInt32(typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty(field).GetValue(someClass));
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @EdwardDuffy Glad to help :) I just edited in another way, though

Comment: Okay, minor problem, I tried to use Func<SomeClass, IComparable> and now I'm getting an error saying > can't be applied to IComparable.

Comment: @EdwardDuffy For that, you need to use `IComparable.CompareTo()` instead of `>`/`<`

Comment: Do decimal and int inherit from IComparable?

Comment: @EdwardDuffy Yes, they do: [int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, you've just helped knock nearly 500 lines of _awfully_  factored code off my project!

Comment: @EdwardDuffy Then you are in the right path if you thought there should be a better way. You are welcome!